# how and where must add button in fragment class which is used for sliding menu?

Tags: android, button, android-fragmentactivity, slidingmenu

I'm reading and working with a tutorial which is about how create sliding menu in android app  ...
the address of tutorial is [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) ..
the activity-main.xml is this :

```
//activity-main.xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

actually, I want to add a button to `fragment_find_people.xml` layout to show a simple toast ...

```
//fragment_find_people.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="enter" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

i have not work with fragment class and view so i am confused ...
i found out i could not create Button object in "FindPeopleFragment" class which extend  Fragment  ....
there is class which is :

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {
Button btnAdd;
public FindPeopleFragment(){
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
    return rootView;

}

}
```

when I wrote :

```
    btnAdd=(Button)this.....
```

it shows no suggestion to find element by id ... no thing showed ... :( when I create a button in onCreate of MainActivity
the program crashed !!!:(

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
..
...
..  
btnADD=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
btnADD.setOnClickListener(new clickListener());
}
.
class clickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
.
 }
```

where i must create my Button and call its OnClickListener ???

thanks for helping

Comment: You need to have a Fragment class (or subclass of your MainActivity) and you can set it's functionality in it's onCreate. By default, at least in eclipse, your Fragment class is setup as something like PlaceHolderFragment in your MainActivity. There, you will inflate your fragment layout and set your view listeners. You can also do all of this in XML, but I avoid XML when I can as I am not as good at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a layout which holds the listview inside of the sliding menu,and by this you could add views before / after the sliding menu. for example.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/user_fc"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.04"
         android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
         android:textStyle="italic" />
 <ListView
         android:id="@+id/slider_list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:divider="@android:color/black"
         android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

the textView will appear just before the sliding menu listview.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was in [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) tutorial ... in the "FindPeopleFragment" class and in the "onCreateView" function i  must write it like this

```
  btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTost);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

as you see we have not "this" object hear.... we have "rootView"